# Allow different views for different types of users in django rest class based views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

How do I write the following views using class based view?

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def hotel_list(request):
    # List all hotel or add new .
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Allow GET request for all authenticated users
            hotels = models.Hotel.objects.all()
            serializer = serializers.HotelSerializer(hotels, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response({"message": "not authorized"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            # Allow POST method for super users only
            serializer = serializers.HotelSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response({"message": "not authorized"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I want to allow different permissions for different groups of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create [custom-permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

permissions.py

```
class CreateAdminOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user.is_superuser
        return request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user.is_superuser
        return request.user.is_authenticated
```

use it with [modelviewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) in views.py

```
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from .permissions import CreateAdminOnly

class CreateListRetrieveViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                mixins.ListModelMixin,
                                viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = models.Hotel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HotelSerializer
    permission_classes = [CreateAdminOnly]
```

Comment: It's not working. I can make POST request even without any authentication.

Comment: fixed, i added  the method  `has_permission`

Comment: glad to help you)